# Zonal stats for complete pixels qgis

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics

I am trying to extract zonal statistics from raster imagery using polygons in QGIS 3.2.1, but I only want to use values from those pixels that are completely included in the polygons, ¿how to do this?

Answer for the comment: 
I'm agree but I have a problem when I polygonize my raster. This is because similar values form bigger polygons and then I have problems to select by location because the polygon is more big than a pixel –

[image]

Comment: I tried with zonal stats but it takes into account the pixels that are cutted

Answer (score 3):

It seems you need to `clip raster to mask layer` without including pixels that overlap the edge of the mask layer.

**`Polygonize` your raster.**

[image]

**Use `Select by location` tool to select features in Vectorized layer that fall within the polygon layer.**
[image]
[image]

**`Clip  raster by mask layer` using the selected features of the Vectorized layer as the mask layer. Don't crop the extent.**
[image]

[image]

**Run Zonal Stats on the clipped raster.**

Comment: I'm agree but I have a problem when I polygonize my raster. This is because similar values form bigger polygons and then I have problems to select by location because the polygon is more big than a pixel